# How to execute a controller method call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Good afternoon!
I have the following controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowComparisonResultSimpleViewFromJs(List<GetDocumentList_Result> documents,
        GetAgreementNumberKktShiftInfo_Result infoResult)
{
    ViewBag.DisplayName = CurrentUser?.DisplayName;
    ViewBag.Documents = documents;
    ViewBag.DocumentCount = Convert.ToString(documents.Count());

    return View("ComparisonResultSimpleView", infoResult);  
}
```

I also have an InputKktShiftView view that has a button click handler. In it I need to call the controller method specified above, as a result, the ComparisonResultSimpleView page is loaded. 
Here is an example of a button click handler:

```
<script>
function OnClick(s, e) {
    //Data for example:
    var parameterModel = {
        FnFactoryNumber: '1',//'9280440300664345',
        ShiftNumber: 38
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/TaxcomProblems/GetInputKktShiftJsonResult',
        data: parameterModel
    }).success(function(data) {

        if (data.IsValid) {
            if (data.InfoResult != null) {

                var jsData = {
                    documents: data.Documents,
                    infoResult: data.InfoResult
                };

                //Here you need to call the /TaxcomProblems/ShowComparisonResultSimpleViewFromJs method

                //$.ajax({
                //    type: 'POST',
                //    url: '/TaxcomProblems/ShowComparisonResultSimpleViewFromJs',
                //    data: jsData,
                //    dataType:'html',
                //    success: function(result) {
                //        var view = $("ComparisonResultSimpleView");
                //        view.html(result);
                //    }
                //});

            } else {
                dxConfirm("Перейти на страницу выбора ККТ?")
                    .success(function() {
                        window.location.href = "/TaxcomProblems/ShowChoiceKktView";
                    });
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Here is the code for my ComparisonResultSimpleView page:

```
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@using BonusProgramAPI.Tools
@model BonusProgramAPI.EF.GetAgreementNumberKktShiftInfo_Result

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Результаты для ККТ и смены";
   ViewBag.agreementNumber = Model?.agreementNumber;
   ViewBag.outletId = Model?.outletId;
   ViewBag.fnFactoryNumber = Model?.fnFactoryNumber;
   ViewBag.openDateTime = Model?.openDateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
   ViewBag.shiftNumber = Model?.shiftNumber;
}

<script>
   function OnBtnGetKktInfoClick(s, e) {
      pcKktInfo.Show();
   }
</script>


@Html.DevExpress().FormLayout(settings =>
{
   settings.Name = "rootLayout";
   settings.Items.AddGroupItem(group =>
   {
     @* some code *@
   }
}).GetHtml()

@* PopupControls: *@
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("PopupControlKktInfoPartialView");
    Html.RenderPartial("PopupControlShiftInfoPartialView");
 }
```

Question: How do I call the ShowComparisonResultSimpleViewFromJs method of the TaxcomProblems controller so that the ComparisonResultSimpleView page displays?
P.S.: If I use ajax, then I call the specified method correctly (all data is transferred to it correctly), but the specified page is not displayed, and the current page remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax post will not refresh the page. You have to do it by yourself. Also you are sending the full page from the `ShowComparisonResultSimpleViewFromJs` action with the following code:

```
return View("ComparisonResultSimpleView", infoResult);
```

What you can do is make the `ShowComparisonResultSimpleViewFromJs` action return partial content (html) instead of full page content. And then add the returned data in a div on the success method of the ajax call.

To return partial view write:

```
return PartialView("~/views/ComparisonResultSimpleView.cshtml", infoResult);
```

Also in the javascript codes note that the element selector is missing a class or Id notation. You can simply write:

```
$("#ComparisonResultSimpleView").html(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your jquery selector is attempting to get the element

```
<ComparisonResultSimpleView></ComparisonResultSimpleView>
```

from here

```
success: function(result) {
                     var view = $("ComparisonResultSimpleView");
                     view.html(result);
                  }
```

Do you mean to select the element with id = ComparisonResultSimpleView ?

```
<div id="ComparisonResultSimpleView"></div>
```

You will need to add "#" to your selector like so:

```
success: function(result) {
                     var view = $("#ComparisonResultSimpleView");
                     view.html(result);
                  }
```

Want to know if the selector is correct?
Run the following line in your page's browser console

```
$("#ComparisonResultSimpleView").length; // greater than zero means the number of elements matching selector. Zero means no match.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added the ComparisonResultSimpleViev page code above. It is written mainly using the elements of DevExpress MVC. I wonder where to add the div element?

Comment: I commented out the ajax code in the OnClick method of the InputKktShiftView page, which should call the ComparisonResultSimpleView page, because I don’t know if this is the way to solve the problem or not.

Comment: Earned. As I understand it, you need to add a div to the InputKktShiftView page. That is, I insert the code of the ComparisonResultSimpleView page into the InputKktShiftView page, and the code of the latter is obtained as PartialView.

Comment: Question: is there another way to call another page from the current page in the JavaScript?

Comment: If it is simply another page, you can call: window.location.href = "https://example.com/myotherpage"; or if in the same website, use it relatively window.location.href = "/myotherpage".

Comment: I have a POST controller method with class type parameters.

Comment: Are you saying you want to return to another page after calling the POST method ?

Comment: Yes. I want to return to another page calling the POST method.

Comment: 2 ways, your post method can return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK), then in your javascript success: function(){} can call window.location.href.       Otherwise, you have to write your js to store the data in a form and submitting the form in js (which can be an entirely new question all together ). Once you submit the form, your controller action in C# can return RedirectToAction("MyOtherActionName");

Comment: And you can give some example or link to an example. I'm just new to ASP.Net MVC. It’s just that after DX Winforms MVVM it’s very difficult to switch to ASP. No MVC

Comment: You can reference Html.BeginForm syntax for MVC 5 official docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view

Comment: If you intend to use ajax submission, then look through this example as well: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-5-ajax-beginform-ajaxoptions-onsuccess-onfailure/